# Why are the subplots not displayed in subplot?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I want to create a 2x2 plot with only 3 subplots. 1 bar plot and two pieplots. See code:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go 
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

years = [1980, 1980, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988,
         1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997,
         1998, 1999 ,2000 ,2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
         2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015,
         2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]
freq = [173,1368,2238,4135,5455,6280,7470,6580,7537,8781,10894,14788,20562,27637,
        32446,32665,30374,28234,24235,22312,16817,20222,24080,30398,30230,27462,
        33582,28908,31648,26579,29121,31216,34574,34271,32570,32531,43390,46761,
        55920,34675,0]

values_in = [872641, 13994, 39055, 8985]
labels_in = ['Company', 'Goverment (NGO)', 'Individual', 'University']

values_cty = [297286, 175039, 170002, 66060, 35678, 31959, 26268, 24724, 22058, 17902],
labels_cty = ['Japan', 'Germany', 'USA', 'France' ,'Italy' ,'Switzerland' , 'Korea',
          'Great Brtian', 'Netherlands', 'China(PRC)']

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=2,
    specs=[[{"colspan": 2}, None],[{'type':'pie'}, {'type':'pie'}]],
    subplot_titles=("Patents","Countries", "Institutions"))

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=years, y=freq),row=1,col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=labels_cty, values=values_cty),
                 row=2, col=1)
fig.add_trace(go.Pie(labels=labels_in, values=values_in),
                 row=2, col=2)
```

[image]

I do not get why the piecharts are not displayed. There is no error code.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you're only missing a few domain attributes that you'll need for some subplots such as `go.Pie()`:

```
domain=dict(x=[0, 0.5]
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Code:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

years = [1980, 1980, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988,
         1989, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997,
         1998, 1999 ,2000 ,2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
         2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015,
         2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]
freq = [173,1368,2238,4135,5455,6280,7470,6580,7537,8781,10894,14788,20562,27637,
        32446,32665,30374,28234,24235,22312,16817,20222,24080,30398,30230,27462,
        33582,28908,31648,26579,29121,31216,34574,34271,32570,32531,43390,46761,
        55920,34675,0]

values_in = [872641, 13994, 39055, 8985]
labels_in = ['Company', 'Goverment (NGO)', 'Individual', 'University']

values_cty = [297286, 175039, 170002, 66060, 35678, 31959, 26268, 24724, 22058, 17902]
labels_cty = ['Japan', 'Germany', 'USA', 'France' ,'Italy' ,'Switzerland' , 'Korea',
          'Great Brtian', 'Netherlands', 'China(PRC)']

fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=2,
    specs=[[{"colspan": 2}, None],[{'type':'pie'}, {'type':'pie'}]],
    subplot_titles=("Patents","Countries", "Institutions"))

fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=years, y=freq),row=1,col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Pie(
     values= [872641, 13994, 39055, 8985],
     labels=labels_in,
     domain=dict(x=[0, 0.5]),
     ), 
     row=2, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Pie(
     values=values_cty,
     labels=labels_cty,
     domain=dict(x=[0.5, 1.0]),
     ),
    row=2, col=2)

fig.show()
```

Comment: you may have a tip on how i tackle the problem with the overlap in subplot2 (direction='clockwise' didnt work out) and how to increase size of the pie charts?

Comment: @Epimetheus- Probably, yes. If you take the time to post it as a new question then I'll make sure to take a look at it when I find the time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66064756/how-to-change-subplot-size-and-decrease-space-between-subplot